# Does install.packages update an already installed package in R?

Tags: r

When using `install.packages()` in R, does it uninstall the currently installed version of the package and install the latest version (even if the version number hasn't changed)?

Comment: There is `?update.packages`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas -- `update.packages` would work fine as long as a newer version is available (according to the help page), however, I'm guessing that a "newer" version is one that has an updated version number.  In my case, I'm making minor updates to a package which I have not yet released, so I'm not bothering to update the version number.

Comment: OK, then you should state in the question that it's your package you are updating, a package not yet released. The issue, I believe, is different.